# Why does the "watch" command starts two "watch" and a "sh" process?

Tags: command-line, sh, watch-command

When I tried to run `watch ps` command I got the following result:

```
Every 2.0s: ps                                          Thu Jul 31 14:06:45 2014

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4329 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 4380 pts/1    00:00:00 watch
 4381 pts/1    00:00:00 watch
 4382 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
 4383 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Why does this command starts two `watch` processes instead of one?

Also why does watch starts an instance of `sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the answer we need to look at the watch command [source code](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/source/784c6eda1c0da81c6b70f860768b984b9a731a6e:watch.c).

1. You can see two `watch` processes because `watch` [forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) (line 380) a new process each time it has to run the command:

   [image]
2. The extra `sh` process is here because `watch` calls the **system()** function (line 399) and by default it runs the specified command with `/bin/sh -c`. Look at the `system` man page:

> ```
> NAME
>        system - execute a shell command
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <stdlib.h>
>
>        int system(const char *command);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
>        command, and returns after the command has been completed.  During exe‐
>        cution  of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT
>        will be ignored.
> ```